# How does [] make a difference in Java regex?

Tags: java, regex, validation, utf-8

I have a regex for validation of UTF-8 characters.

```
String regex = "[\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{N}\\p{P}\\p{Z}\\p{S}\\p{C}]*"
```

I wanted to do a range check too so I modified it to

```
String regex = "[[\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{N}\\p{P}\\p{Z}\\p{S}\\p{C}]*]"
String rangeRegex = regex + "{0,30}"
```

Notice that it’s the same regex I just wrapped it with `[ ]`.

Now I can validate with the range by using `rangeRegex` but `regex` is now not validating UTF-8 chars.

My question is: how is `[]` affecting `regex`? If I remove `[]` from the original regex it will validate UTF-8 chars but not with range. If I put `[]` it will validate with range but not without range!

sample test code -

```
public class Test {

    static String regex =  "[[\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{N}\\p{P}\\p{Z}\\p{S}\\p{C}]*]" ;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userId = null;
        //testUserId(userId);
        userId = "";
        testUserId(userId);
        userId = "æÆbBcCćĆčČçďĎǳǲdzsDzs";
        testUserId(userId);
        userId = "test123";
        testUserId(userId);
        userId = "abcxyzsd";
        testUserId(userId);

        String zip = "i«♣│axy";
        testZip(zip);
        zip = "331fsdfsdfasdfasd02c3";
        testZip(zip);
        zip = "331";
        testZip(zip);

    }

    /**
     * without range check
     * @param userId
     */
    static void testUserId(String userId){
        boolean pass = true;
        if ( !stringValidator(userId, regex)) {
            pass = false;
        }
        System.out.println(pass);
    }

    /**
     * with a range check
     * @param zip
     */
    static void testZip(String zip){
        boolean pass = true;
        String regex1 = regex + "{0,10}";
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(zip) && !stringValidator(zip, regex1)) {
            pass = false;
        }
        System.out.println(pass);
    }

    static boolean stringValidator(String str, String regex) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
}
```

Comment: the second one is like the first one, except the character class contains `[`, and all of it is followed by 0-30 times `]`

Comment: All answers are a bit wrong: the square brackets inside square brackets are *ignored*.

Comment: Please show how you use the code and your sample input. I see you do not have a correct explanation yet. It is difficult to guess. Just note that I also think you need `[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{P}\p{Z}\p{S}\p{C}]{0,30}`. If you are using `matcher.matches` you will match a string of 0 to 30 characters belonging to the Unicode category classes above.

Comment: @stribizhev edited post to include sample test code. Thank you.

Comment: @vermap: Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanations given are rather wrong for Java regex.

**In Java, unescaped paired square brackets inside a character class are not treated as literal `[` and `]` characters**. They have a special meaning in [Java character classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html):

> `[a-d[m-p]]`      `a` through `d`, or `m` through `p`: `[a-dm-p]` **(union)**
>   `[a-z&&[def]]`    `d`, `e`, or `f` **(intersection)**
>   `[a-z&&[^bc]]`  `a` through `z`, except for `b` and `c`: `[ad-z]` **(subtraction)**
>   `[a-z&&[^m-p]]`    `a` through `z`, and not `m` through `p`: `[a-lq-z]` **(subtraction)**

So, when you add a `[...]` to your regex, you get a union of the previous regex pattern with literal `*` character and means *match either `[\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{N}\\p{P}\\p{Z}\\p{S}\\p{C}]` or a literal `*`*.

Also, `[[\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{N}\\p{P}\\p{Z}\\p{S}\\p{C}]*]` is equal to `[\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{N}\\p{P}\\p{Z}\\p{S}\\p{C}*]` as **`*` symbol inside a character class stops being a special character (a quantifier) and becomes a literal asterisk symbol**.

**If you use `[[]]`, the engine will throw an exception: `Unclosed character class near index 3`**

See [this IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/1d7U2v):

```
System.out.println("abc[]".replaceAll("[[abc]]", "")); // => []
System.out.println("abc[]".replaceAll("[[]]", "")); // => error
```

Whenever you need to *check the length of a string with regex*, you need [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) and a [limiting quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit). Anchors are automatically added when a regex is used with [`Matcher#matches` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

> The `matches` method **attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern**.

Example code:

```
String regex = "[\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{N}\\p{P}\\p{Z}\\p{S}\\p{C}]";
String new_regex = regex + "{0,30}"; 
System.out.println("Some string".matches(new_regex)); // => true
```

See [this IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/fZReED)

**UPDATE**

Here is [commented code of yours](http://ideone.com/I0jdOc):

```
String userId = "";
testUserId(userId); // false - Correct as we test an empty string with an at-least-one-char regex
userId = "æÆbBcCćĆčČçďĎǳǲdzsDzs";
testUserId(userId); // false - Correct as we only match 1 character string, others fail
userId = "test123";
testUserId(userId); // false - see above
userId = "abcxyzsd";
testUserId(userId); // false - see above

String zip = "i«♣│axy";
testZip(zip);                    // true - OK, 7-symbol string matches against [...]{0,10} regex
zip = "331fsdfsdfasdfasd02c3";
testZip(zip);                 // false - OK, 21-symbol string does not match a regex that requires only 0 to 10 characters
zip = "331";          
testZip(zip);                // true - OK, 3-symbol string matches against [...]{0,10} regex
```

Comment: This will return true for a string more than 30 chars long

Comment: @vermap: No way. With `matches`, the whole input should match.

Comment: yes it is 'String regex =  "[\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{N}\\p{P}\\p{Z}\\p{S}\\p{C}]*" ;
  String new_regex = regex + "{0,30}"; 
  System.out.println("Some stdsdfsfdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfasdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdring".matches(new_regex));' returning true

Comment: Please check my updated answer with comments. If there is anything unclear, let me know.

Comment: The inner `[]` are not ignored. They define a nested character class, which union with the outer character class which contains `*`.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I just meant that paired unescaped square brackets inside a character class are not interpreted as literal characters and `[abc]` is the same as `[[abc]]`.I tried to explain it in a human way and overdid with simplifications. I will add some more details to my answer when I'm back to desktop.

Comment: @stribizhev thanks for explanation, my problem was that i was trying to use both * and range ({0,10}) at the same time, whereas the * is ignoring the range check.

Answer (score 2):

`*` means 0 or more, so it is almost like `{0,}`. i.e. you can replace the `*` with `{0,30}` and it should do what you want:

```
[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{P}\p{Z}\p{S}\p{C}]{0,30}
```

`[]` creates a character class, so `[[]]` would be "a character class of just `[` followed by `]` since the first `]` closes the character class prematurely and doesn't really do what you want.

---

Also correct me if I'm wrong, but the character list you are generating is pretty much everything, so you could go with `.{0,30}` for the same effect.

Comment: But does `.` match line breaks?

Comment: @Xufox good point ... depends on the regex settings usually so it may not match newlines while `\p{S}` might match them ... but I'm not sure if it does either.

Comment: yeah thats true i am basically allowing everything. if i dont put * at the end (zero or more) it wont validate anything.

Comment: `[[]] would be "a character class of just [ followed by ]` Sorry, but it's not the case for Java. Since Java has nested character class, it will throw an exception as explained in the other answer.

Comment: Another thing, in Java, `\p{C}` doesn't match Cn category (unassigned/reserved code points), so (regardless of whether it's a bug or not) it's technically not equivalent to `.{0,30}`, though if we want to match any code point `(?s).{0,30}` should be used instead.